# How to take into account the "0" in VBA for numbers format as 01 to 09?

Tags: excel, vba

Cell P2 in Sheet1 contains the value "01" (Custom format Cells : 00), however VBA reads it as "1".
I'm using this line of code for every week of the year. It's just that it does not work from Week 1 to 9 as the related file's names that I want to open end with a double digit number 01, 02, ...

```
Workbooks.Open "L:\Path\2021\Indicators\otherpath\W" & _
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("P2") + 1 & "\ZMM_file wk" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("P2") + 1 & ".xlsx"
```

Thank you.

Comment: You could force it to have at least 2 numbers using Format. `Format(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("P2") + 1,"00")` if that's what you're trying to do. It's one method.

Comment: It works perfectly, I did not know that. Thank you Simon.